# Problem using Uploadify plugin(JQuery) with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, upload

I have a Masterpage like that :

```
...
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
</head>
...
```

And in my Aspx page :

```
...

<asp:Content ID="HeadContentFromPage" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
   <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadify.css" />
   <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery.noConflict();
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
         jQuery("#<%=fupImagem.ClientID %>").fileUpload({
                'uploader': 'uploadify.swf',
                'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
                'script': 'Uploader.ashx',
                'folder': 'uploads',
                'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': true
         });
      }
   );
   </script>

</asp:Content>
...
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fupImage" runat="server" CssClass="txtBig" />
...
```

I got that error when loading that page :

**Erro: jQuery("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fupImagem").fileUpload is not a function**

Any idea whats wrong?

Paul

Comment: Which version of uploadify are you using? One of the more recent updates changed the upload command from fileUpload() to uploadifyUpload().

Comment: Just an aside, you don't need to call jQuery.noConflict() if you are going to reference jQuery using its full name. This is only for if you are going to use the $ alias, so it doesn't conflict with other js libs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery("#<%=fupImagem.ClientID %>").uploadify({
```

It changed from `fileUpload` to `uploadify` in version 2.0.0. See the [changelog](http://www.uploadify.com/download/):

```
Function changed to uploadify()
fileUpload()           – uploadify()
fileUploadStart()      - uploadifyUpload()
fileUploadSettings()   - uploadifySettings()
fileUploadCancel()     - uploadifyCancel()
fileUploadClearQueue() – uploadifyClearQueue()
```